# "Cannot find symbol error" in my Triangle class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, symbols

I can't figure out why I'm getting the *cannot find symbol* errors for the num and triangle type variables.

This is the class:

```
public class Triangle
{
    private int s1;
    private int s2;
    private int s3;

    public Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3)
{
        s1= num1;
        s2= num2;
        s3= num3;
}

    public String toString()
    {
    return (s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
    }

    public boolean is_equilateral(){
if(s1==s2 && s2==s3 && s3==s1)
    {
    return Triangle.is_equilateral;
    }
else
{
    return false;
}
}

    public boolean is_isosceles(){
if((s1==s2)||(s2==s3)||(s3==s1))
{
    return Triangle.is_isosceles;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

    public boolean is_scalene(){
if(s1!=s2 && s2!=s3 && s3!=s1)
{
    return Triangle.is_scalene;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}


    }
```

and this is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment5 {

   //===========================================================
   // Create and determine properties of various triangles.
   //===========================================================
   public static void main (String[] args) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      String another;
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle: ");
         num1 = console.nextInt();
         num2 = console.nextInt();
         num3 = console.nextInt();

         Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle (num1, num2, num3);


        System.out.println(myTriangle.toString() + " triangle:");

        //check the isosceles
        if (myTriangle.is_isosceles())
           System.out.println("\tIt is isosceles");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not isosceles");

        //check the equilateral
        if (myTriangle.is_equilateral())
           System.out.println("\tIt is equilateral");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not a equilateral");

        //check the scalene
        if (myTriangle.is_scalene())
           System.out.println("\tIt is scalene");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not scalene");


        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Check another Triangle (y/n)? ");
        another = console.next();

    } while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));


   }  // method main

}  // class Assignment5
```

I'm fairly new to Java so sorry if this is an obvious problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention the program is a test program that I cannot edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int s1; // these belong to the class
private int s2;
private int s3;

public Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3) // these belong to the constructor
{
        s1= num1; // num1 isn't declared anywhere
        s2= num2;
        s3= num3;
}
```

Both your class variables and the arguments to your constructor are named `s1` - `s3`.

You need to either change the arguments to `num1` - `num3`, or change the assignment statements to use the `this` keyword to refer to the class variables.  Here's the first method:

```
private int s1; // these belong to the class
private int s2;
private int s3;

public Triangle (int num1, int num2, int num3) // these belong to the constructor
{
        s1 = num1;
        s2 = num2;
        s3 = num3;
}
```

[Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Okay, so I changed the instance variables to side1-side3, but now I'm getting an error saying it ccannot find the symbol s1-s3.

Comment: @DarbyVance Those aren't what you should have changed.  The arguments are what's in parentheses. `Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3)`

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. I really appreciate the help. Sorry, I'm still having a little trouble with some of the basic concepts.

Comment: @DarbyVance No problem. I posted a link to a really good set of comprehensive Java Tutorials at the end of my answer.

Comment: Cool, this will be really helpful.

Comment: Oh, and do you know why it "cannot find the symbol" for is_equilateral, is_isosceles, and is_scalene?

Comment: @DarbyVance Yes, that's because of lines like `return Triangle.is_equilateral;`  There is no variable at the class level named `is_equilateral`.  That method should just return `true` if all sides are equal and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I really appreciate the link to. Do you have any other recommended material for java beginners.

Comment: @DarbyVance There's a book called "Head First Java" that's probably the best beginner's guide to any programming language that I've read.