# Cannot find symbol error in my Triangle class

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error

For some reason I keep getting the *cannot find symbol error* for Triangle.is_equilateral, Triangle.is_isosceles, and Triangle.is_scalene.

Here is the Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle
{
    private int s1;
    private int s2;
    private int s3;

    public Triangle (int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
        s1= num1;
        s2= num2;
        s3= num3;
}

    public String toString()
    {
    return (s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
    }

    public boolean is_equilateral(){
if(s1==s2 && s2==s3 && s3==s1)
    {
    return Triangle.is_equilateral;
    }
else
{
    return false;
}
}

    public boolean is_isosceles(){
if((s1==s2)||(s2==s3)||(s3==s1))
{
    return Triangle.is_isosceles;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

    public boolean is_scalene(){
if(s1!=s2 && s2!=s3 && s3!=s1)
{
    return Triangle.is_scalene;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}


    }
```

and here is the test program:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      String another;
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle: ");
         num1 = console.nextInt();
         num2 = console.nextInt();
         num3 = console.nextInt();

         Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle (num1, num2, num3);


        System.out.println(myTriangle.toString() + " triangle:");

        //check the isosceles
        if (myTriangle.is_isosceles())
           System.out.println("\tIt is isosceles");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not isosceles");

        //check the equilateral
        if (myTriangle.is_equilateral())
           System.out.println("\tIt is equilateral");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not a equilateral");

        //check the scalene
        if (myTriangle.is_scalene())
           System.out.println("\tIt is scalene");
        else
           System.out.println("\tIt is not scalene");


        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Check another Triangle (y/n)? ");
        another = console.next();

    } while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));


   }  // method main

}  // class Assignment5
```

Thanks for any help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cannot find symbol error" in my Triangle class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461214/cannot-find-symbol-error-in-my-triangle-class)

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the members `is_equilateral`, `is_isosceles`, `is_scalene` inside your class `Triangle`
you need to add them:
`private bool is_equilateral;`
`private bool is_isosceles;`
`private bool is_scalene;`